# How do I configure Serverless Framework for dotenv in a monorepo for specific sub-folders?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, monorepo, dotenv, npm-workspaces

I've got a basic monorepo using npm workspaces. Folder structure is like so:

```
my-app/
├── node_modules
├── packages/
│   └── lambda/
│       ├── .env (the one I want)
│       ├── package.json
│       └── prototype.ts
├── .env (the one that works)
├── package.json
└── serverless.yml
```

My `serverless.yml` file:

```
service: prototype-serverless-api
frameworkVersion: '3'
useDotenv: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin

functions:
  routesHandler:
    handler: ./packages/lambda/prototype.routesHandler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /movies
          method: get
          cors: true

custom:
  serverlessPluginTypescript:
    tsConfigFileLocation: './tsconfig.base.json'
```

Serverless only exists in my project for local debugging, and it works as-is with `serverless.yml` in the root of the repo, but it's also forcing me to place my `.env` file in the root and won't allow me to place individual `.env` files into different projects inside of the `/packages` folder, like I've got in the image above. It only recognizes the env vars if it's in the root.

Really, I'd like `serverless.yml` to also reside inside the `/packages/lambda` folder if possible, since that's the only place it's relevant.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hey, can you please create an [ASCII `tree` instead](https://ascii-tree-generator.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah, got it...nevermind. This at the top of my lambda file:

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config({ path: "packages/lambda/.env" });
```